# What is the type of returned result of webservice?

Tags: c#

I am new to c# as well as new to stack-overflow.I got some code that call some webservice and get result.

```html
 public async void getJobs(Func<List<Dictionary<string, string>>, int> callback)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
                var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(response.Content.ContentToString());
                callback(list);
            }
        }
```

I actually want to implement its callback function, but i am confused what is the type of list variable. Is it List<...> , Dictionary of array or something else.

Thanks

Comment: It's `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`, as can be seen from both the first generic argument of the type of `callback` and from the call to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`

Comment: Ok . . .Thankyou Bart. One more thing , will you please tell me what is the type of response.

Comment: Have a look at [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx).